# Spark - split csv file using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have the following schema of csv file

```
(Id, OwnerUserId, CreationDate, ClosedDate, Score, Title, Body)
```

And I would like to split the data using:

```
val splitComma = file.map(x => x.split (",")
val splitComma = file.map(x => x.split (",(?![^<>]*</>)(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"))
```

both of them didn't work, the below is sample of my csv file :

```
90,58,2008-08-01T14:41:24Z,2012-12-26T03:45:49Z,144,Good branching and merging tutorials for TortoiseSVN?,"<p>Are there any really good tutorials explaining <a href=""http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html"" rel=""nofollow"">branching and merging</a> with Apache Subversion? </p>

<p>All the better if it's specific to TortoiseSVN client.</p>
"
120,83,2008-08-01T15:50:08Z,NA,21,ASP.NET Site Maps,"<p>Has anyone got experience creating <strong>SQL-based ASP.NET</strong> site-map providers?</p>

<p>I've got the default XML file <code>web.sitemap</code> working properly with my Menu and <strong>SiteMapPath</strong> controls, but I'll need a way for the users of my site to create and modify pages dynamically.</p>

<p>I need to tie page viewing permissions into the standard <code>ASP.NET</code> membership system as well.</p>
"
180,2089740,2008-08-01T18:42:19Z,NA,53,Function for creating color wheels,"<p>This is something I've pseudo-solved many times and never quite found a solution. That's stuck with me. The problem is to come up with a way to generate <code>N</code> colors, that are as distinguishable as possible where <code>N</code> is a parameter.</p>
"
```

What's the best way to work with this ?

Comment: Use the `spark-csv` library. `split(",")` doesn't always work for all data

Comment: How many "lines" do you have in a csv file (disregarding the fact that one "line" can be split across multiple lines because of the last field with a HTML-like content with new lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** load CSVs with multi-line values (i.e. newlines within cells) using Spark: the underlying `HadoopInputFormat` will split the file based on newlines, disregarding the CSV's encapsulating double-quotes, so there isn't much Spark can do about it (see discussion [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/72)).

Unfortunately that means you'll have to find some why of "cleaning" your data (e.g. replacing newlines with some placeholder) before writing it to disk or loading it using Spark.